# C# 3.0 Save itextsharp pdf to database using MemoryStream

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, memorystream

I'm trying to save to databse a pdf file generated by itextsharp. But, I haven't been successfully so far.

I'm using Linq to sql.

Here's the code:

```
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Document d = new Document(PageSize.A4, 60, 60, 40, 40);
            PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(d, ms);
            w.CloseStream = false;

            string txtTemplate = "";
            Encoding en = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/templates/CessaoDireitosDica.txt"), en);
            txtTemplate  = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            string conselhos = "";

            Font font = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 11, Font.NORMAL);
            font.SetColor(0xC6, 0xC6, 0xC6);

            Paragraph txtBody = new Paragraph(txtTemplate, font);

            txtBody .SetAlignment(ElementTags.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);

            d.Open();
            d.Add(txtBody);
            d.Close();

            byte[] pdfDone = ms.ToArray();
            w.Flush();
            ms.Flush();
            ms.Close();

            return pdfDone;
```

It throws no error, but it doesn't save nothing in DB. The DB field is an "image" field type. 
I also use this code to render a pdf on the fly (I cut off the byte[] pdfDone... and return the MemoryStream).

I don't know what can be wrong... And debugging, I could also see that byte[] pdfDone has a value (something like 3487), but nothing is saved to DB.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see *any* database code in there. I'd also recommend using `using` statements instead of all the manual closing... beyond that, it sounds like it's really just an itextsharp issue.

Comment: Unfortunately iTextSharp doesn't implement IDisposable, but I agree on the lack of database code.

Comment: This code is a part of a method that returns an array of bytes to be saved. The database code is not shown here and the code is right. I discovered the error. It was on a transaction I was using. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function byte[] CreatePdf(){
            byte[] result;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Document pDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pDoc, ms);
                pDoc.Open();

                //here you can create your own pdf.

                pDoc.Close();
                result = ms.GetBuffer();
            }

            return result;
}
```